# How to kill multiprocess with selenium chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm terminating multiprocess thread after certain period and when I terminate it won't kill the chromedriver.
This is a sample of the code (kept it simple):

```
def start_thread(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)

urls=[]
threads=[]
for counter in range(urls):
    thread = multiprocessing.Process( target=start_thread,name=f'start_thread_{counter}', args=[url])
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

sleep(10)
for t in threads:
    t.terminate()
```

The thread is indeed terminated but the chromedriver isn't.
I wanted to know if there's any option for me to kill the driver when I terminate the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because ways to hijack the session from children seem to no-longer work, you are stuck with having to manually kill chrome and the webdriver and all its children using psutils, until they put sessions hijacking into the webdrivers.

```py
import time
import multiprocessing
from selenium import webdriver
import psutil


def start_thread(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(30)


def get_all_children(proc: psutil.Process):
    try:
        if len(proc.children()) == 0:
            return []
        else:
            returned_list = []
            for item in proc.children():
                returned_list.append(item)
                returned_list.extend(get_all_children(item))
            return returned_list
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
        return []


if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls = ['http://www.python.org','http://www.python.org']
    threads = []
    for counter in range(len(urls)):
        thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_thread, name=f'start_thread_{counter}', args=(urls[counter],))
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    time.sleep(5)
    for t in threads:
        children = get_all_children(psutil.Process(pid=t.pid))
        t.terminate()
        for child in children:
            try:
                child.terminate()
            except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
                pass  # in case child was already dead

        time.sleep(5)  # to see what's happening
```

searching for children this way is somewhat necessary because chrome tends to open a lot of children, althought it might be limited to only 2 children on windows, this is may not be the case for other systems.

Comment: This will kill all of them, How can I kill specific one using data from the thread name/id ?

Comment: @user2396640 i've modified it to search only for children of said process